# durandal.js viewmodel communication

Tags: javascript, durandal

Does anyone know what's the easiest way to get an instance of a view model within another view model. To be more specific, i would like to load the instance of one view model into another view model so that the latter can call methods of the former.

Does durandal keep a list of all view models that were used during the composition?

I guess one way to deal with that is applying the pub/sub pattern which is supported by durandal. 
Another way would probably be to manually get the view model with the aid of knockout and the dataFor utility function.
However, i would like to know if there is a way to explicitly get the instance of a composed view model.

Note: my modules expose a constructor rather that singleton object

Comment: Is there a reason the first viewmodel isn't constructing the second viewmodel itself?

Comment: @Tyrsius that's the solution that i ultimately used. I just, wondered if durandal offers such a facility, but after a swift look at the source code, i think there is no funcionality similar to that. 
I may ofcource be wrong

Comment: If you really need this tight coupling, the solution @Tyrsius mentioned is probably the best way to do it.  That way the coupling is obvious and intentional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it just by using RequireJS to bring in the viewmodel like you would another module/viewmodel. But you really want to avoid this for viewmodel communication and go with [events](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Events/) instead.

A viewmodel will publish an event through the event aggregator and the other viewmodel is then subscribing to that event.

Check out the “Using Application-Wide Messaging” section [here](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Leveraging-Publish-Subscribe/).

Comment: If the modules expose a constructor, then RequireJS can't be used to get the instance, because you'd just get a constructor.  Otherwise, I agree - events are generally a better way to go.

Comment: I hadn't noticed that bit. I'd definitely go with events then!

Comment: @JosephGabriel: What's wrong with instantiating an object with `new` and that constructor? Also note that an event-driven design is not always appropriate; dictating its use without considering application-specific needs doesn't sound too wise.

Comment: nothing's wrong with it - just won't be able to share data, because two places calling `new` on the same constructor will end up with different instances.